# What's the different between the regex "\\," and ","?

Tags: java, regex, escaping

The below code sample tries to `split` a string by commas (i.e. Passing `\\,` to `String.split()`)

When i change the delimiter to `,` it works fine.
the question is what the difference between using `,` and `\\,` ? And when should I use each one ?

**EDIT**

Also if I put a character other than ',' such as `p`, the statement throws a run-time exception because `p` is not a special regex character to be escaped, so why does it accept to escape commas ?!

the example :

```
String x = "a,b,c,d";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x.split("\\,")));
```

the output :

```
[a, b, c, d]
```

Answer (score 5):

No difference. `\\` is used to escape special characters in regular expressions. The character `,` is not one of them.

Comment: But if I put a character other than `,`, such as `p`, the statement throws a run-time exception because `p` is not a special regex character to be escaped.

Comment: Yes, the Java regex engine is lenient when you escape non-alphanumeric characters unnecessarily (not everyone can remember which metacharacters you do or don't need to escape). With letters, that's different. There is a big difference between `s` and `\s` in a regex.

Comment: @TimPietzcker, is there an official document to backup what you're saying ?

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana: Not official, but http://www.regexguru.com/2008/04/escape-characters-only-when-necessary/ is an interesting read.

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana: `It is an error to use a backslash prior to any alphabetic character that does not denote an escaped construct; these are reserved for future extensions to the regular-expression language. A backslash may be used prior to a non-alphabetic character regardless of whether that character is part of an unescaped construct.` From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 1):

Splitting your input according to `\\,` and `,` would return the same output. Since `,` is not a special character in regex, you don't need to escape that.

But escaped characters have some special meaning . For example `\\s` matches a space character . `\\S` matches a non-space character. `\\d` matches a digit. `\\D` matches a non-digit character. So don't escape alphabets.

Escaping some special characters like `,`, `%`, `#` won't create any problems . But escaping some special characters would differ in their functions. For ex, `\\$` matches a literal `$` symbol, but unescaped `$` matches an end of the line.

And finally, don't escape digits to match a literal digit. For example, `1` and `\\1` has different meaning. `1` matches a literal `1` where `\\1` refers to the first captured group.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say whether "\\," works or seems to work exactly like "," as the split regular expression. I suspect it does based on what I think I know about javac and also about regular expressions.

When you write "\\,", then the string that appears in the .class file is "\,". This is due to how javac treats string literals.

When the regular expression compiler sees "\," it effectively treats that string as "," for reasons similar to those of javac. Of course, there are very good reasons to use '\' in your regular expressions. For example, if the '[' character appeared in the input you were scanning and you wanted your parser to be rigid when looking for '[' followed by digits, then you must write your string literal like "\\[[0-9][0-9]*" or the more concise "\\[\d+". This is because the regular expression compiler treats '[' as special like the former demonstrates.

EDIT: The reason why "\." is treated differently than "\p" is somewhat evident when you read the summary section of the regular expression constructs, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum, that show all the character classes have letters that follow the '\', implying that implementors might consider "\p" an error rather than just simply "p". I would encourage you to not add additional questions to your initial question if for no other reason than to make it less confusing to those who attempt to answer your first question and fail to notice you asked subsequent questions. Instead, you should post a separate question, especially, when it exposes special cases like your follow up question did.

In my opinion, the authors have taken the correct path, which should encourage their users to *completely* understand each regular expression they compose.

Comment: (When you write "\,", then the string that appears in the .class file is "\,".), you mean when he writes "\\," ? You had a SINGLE backslash in the first string you wrote, did you mean that ?

Comment: No, the stackoverflow editor gobbled my extra characters, demonstrating that this is the first time I've attempted to code such things at stackoverflow.

Comment: *In my opinion, the authors have taken the correct path, which should encourage their users to completely understand each regular expression they compose.* - Are you trying to say that being confusing is good?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon, you'll have to explain your comment more fully because your name and your reputation are inconsistent. My kneejerk reaction was to think you were trolling until I saw your reputation. But one thing I can say with boldness is that being confused is good because it is an opportunity for learning. On the other hand, staying confused and not asking for help is bad. Hence, we have things like stackoverflow.

Comment: It looks confusing (as OP asked) that `\\,` is valid while `\\p` is not - you are suggesting this is a good move and somehow *helps you to completely understand ...* - perhaps I have misinterpreted the sentence.

Comment: Yes, it is a good move because it forces people to more completely understand the documentation. It seems obvious that the authors have intended all alpha characters to be reserved in the event that they want to add, say, a \\p character class in the future. If they were to allow \\p and p to mean the same thing now, then they would never be able to add \\p later and maintain former behavior.

Comment: Regardless, it is already documented in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html. Just that no one actually read everything in that long page: `It is an error to use a backslash prior to any alphabetic character that does not denote an escaped construct; these are reserved for future extensions to the regular-expression language. A backslash may be used prior to a non-alphabetic character regardless of whether that character is part of an unescaped construct.`